# How do you prevent Azure AppService Deployments (VSCode) of Node Typscript from creating a JsConfig file alongside the TsConfig file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I have been fighting Azure for the last few hours trying to figure out why my deployments completed, succeeded, and then the app failed to start. Logs pointed to JsConfig.JSON not being allowed with a TsConfig.JSON. I checked my locals and it looked clean, so I dug in the SSH of my webapp and found that the Deployment process added a JsConfig.JSON to my files.

For anyone struggling with this problem - Azure is adding the file because its missing some compiler options that it wants you to have, but it puts it in a new JsConfig, not your TsConfig.

How do we prevent it from doing this and failing successfully, and instead, break the deployment process and let us know *we* need to make an adjustment? Microsofts support is abysmal, so hoping there is an expert out here with thoughts on it.

Thanks community!

Comment: You should raise a support and ask Microsoft to go to the `VSCode team` for help. The technical support of `Azure Web App` should not help you.

Answer (score 0):

An update for anyone checking back around or finding this in the future:
The Visual Studio Azure Extension is no longer the "Best Practice".

Microsoft has offloaded their repos and build pipelines to Github.

From within your AppService Deployment Center, you can automatically attach your Github repo and push a deployment pipeline to Github - its very easy.